# How to make :before content vertically centered?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to make the `:before` contents vertically centered, and also I want **all** the text inside the `blockquote` to be padded to the right of the **:before** contents.

http://jsfiddle.net/m3jEH/

I tried changing the `height`, `line-height` and `min-height`, but none of those allowed me to vertically center and pad the contents (I want this to work for any length the content might be)

Comment: Are you just trying to center those brackets vertically within the blockquote?  You could always absolutely position the :before contents:  http://jsfiddle.net/m3jEH/3/ .  I don't know if this is what you're going for, but it allows for any length of content:  http://jsfiddle.net/m3jEH/4/

Comment: @Joel awesome! if you post it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if i understand right):

```
blockquote {
 background-color: #fcc;
 padding: 20px 20px 20px 60px;
 margin: 30px;
 position: relative
}

blockquote::before {
 content: '{ }';
 color: #b8a08e;
 text-shadow: 0 1px #412917;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 15px;
 margin-right: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-top:-25px
}
```